# Как использовать onRenderModule в системном плагине Joomla

Tags: joomla

Мне нужно внести изменения во все модули Joomla на странице (например поменять одни слова на другие) через системный плагин. Хотелось бы сделать это с помощью `onRenderModule`. Если вставляю в плагин например вот так:

```
class PlgSystemMyname extends JPlugin
{
...
public function onRenderModule($module, $attribs)
    {
        $modulePosition = $attribs['menu'];
        $moduleStyle = $attribs['xhtml'];
        $module->content = str_replace('oldword','newword',$module->content);
    }
}
```

то на странице ничего не меняется. Как правильно использовать `onRenderModule` ?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте аргументы принимать с амперсандом

```
public function onRenderModule(&$module, &$attribs)
```